# Присудили Премию Гран-при или Гран-при?

Tags: заимствования

Как правильно употреблять слово "Гран-при"? Часто слышишь - присудили Премию Гран-при. Но ведь Гран-при в переводе с французского означает "Главная (Большая) премия. Так как правильно говорить "Присудить премию Гран-при Фестиваля" или "Присудить Гран-при Фестиваля"?

Answer (score 2):

Присудить премию Гран-при фестиваля - это,конечно же, плеоназм, так как Гран-при не может не быть премией, и данное слово здесь явно лишнее.

Правда, иногда соседство "Гран-при" и "премии" вовсе не означает избыточность словесной конструкции. Это происходит в случае наличия слова премия в названии конкурса. Например, *Гран-при премии Курёхина*.